# detached thread end of execution

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am currently creating a program which calls native code from within a java environment (NDK).
I have a function that is going to be called a few times from my java code. In this function I create a detached thread that will act as a timer to stop a particular function in my native code.
The code looks like this:

```
void myNativeFunction(){
    std::thread timerTrial(&FluidMechanics::Impl::endTrial,this);
    timerTrial.detach();
}

void endTrial(){
    //code here
    return ;
}
```

The thing is that when endTrial returns I was wondering whether my thread was going to be terminated and all resources freed when I return. Indeed myNativeFunction will be called again a couple of times shortly after that so I don't want to mess up my ressources and memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Any thread specific resources will be automatically released when the *detached* thread returns.

*C++11 draft, N3690, § 30.3.1.7, 10, detach()*

> The thread represented by *this continues execution without the
>   calling thread blocking. When detach() returns, *this no longer
>   represents the possibly continuing thread of execution. **When the
>   thread previously represented by *this ends execution, the
>   implementation shall release any owned resources.**

(emphasis mine).

Comment: Thanks for your quick and precise answer.